# Sonos progressive download

Tags: download, streaming, sonos, progressive

From Sonos documentation I saw that Sonos only supports Mp3 streaming over RTSP or over Shoutcast over HTTP.

Is it possible to streaming tracks in a MP3 format through HTTP using progressive download instead of ShoutCast in Sonos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but could you expand on what you intend by progressive download? Sonos does support byte range seeking: http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/148